# How to JOIN SQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I cant seem to figure out how to join these two table to execute and return all I need in one payload through a single query. Any Help would be very appreciated.

As you will see everything work with the first half of the query if I place a ; at the end of the closing parenthesis following the "IN".

However when I go to join this table with another table propA_Photos, MySQL throws and error. I only want the propA_Photos.photo column joined with the above in one query.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT propA.list_id, propA.list_key, propA.list_value
FROM propA
where list_id = '20141118214124325535000000'
    AND list_key IN ('LIST_1', 'LIST_22', 'LIST_33', 'LIST_31', 'LIST_34', 'LIST_35', 'LIST_36', 'LIST_37', 'LIST_39', 'LIST_40', 'LIST_43', 'LIST_41', 'LIST_46', 'LIST_47') 
INNER JOIN propA_Photos.photo;
```

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Comment: Anyway, `WHERE` goes after `JOIN` and you cannot join with a column.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a join clause, I'm not sure if your database is okay with that.

```
SELECT 
    propA.list_id, propA.list_key, propA.list_value
FROM propA
INNER JOIN propA_Photos.photo
        ON propA_Photos.<<Attr1>> = propA.<<Some_Attribute>>
WHERE list_id = '20141118214124325535000000' 
  AND list_key IN (.. lot of stuff... )
```

Comment: Although your method seems to work best, I am not returning info unless I change INNER to LEFT, and even then it only returns the propA table data not the propA_Photo data in an additional column. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: If returns empty attributes when using LEFT JOIN, and nothing when using INNER Join, the most likely cause is because your join clause in incorrect.

Comment: like @jpw mentioned, Join clauses usually use primary/foreign keys.

you probably are looking for something like:
 
 ON propA_Photos.photo_id = propA.photo_id 
 ON propA_Photos.id = propA.photo_id 

or something like that

Comment: Ok so I know my primary key is the list_id but I never set a foreign key when creating the tables, do you have any suggestion for best implementation regarding this?

Comment: the foreign keys will make joins easier, but they aren't mandatory for joins. like I said, you can join tables using any conditions.

based on which criteria do you want to join? just use that as a join clause

Comment: depending on your database, you might get away with:

`SELECT propA.list_id, propA.list_key, propA.list_value 
FROM propA, propA_Photos.photo
WHERE list_id = '20141118214124325535000000' 
  AND <<some condition that will be obvious after seeing the returned data>>` :)

Answer (score 0):

When joining tables you need to adhere to a specific syntax and order of operators.

The `where` clause should follow the `join` clauses and you need to specify the condition that determines how the tables should be joined using an `on` clause.

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT propA.list_id, propA.list_key, propA.list_value 
FROM propA 
INNER JOIN propA_Photos.photo ON propA.some_column = propA_Photos.some_column
-- the join should likely by using primary key = foreign key
WHERE list_id = '20141118214124325535000000' 
  AND list_key IN (
    'LIST_1',  'LIST_22', 'LIST_33', 'LIST_31', 
    'LIST_34', 'LIST_35', 'LIST_36', 'LIST_37', 
    'LIST_39', 'LIST_40', 'LIST_43', 'LIST_41', 
    'LIST_46', 'LIST_47'
    );
```